Running Total Based on group by and sum of multiple columns pandas
I am working with the below dataset and I am running into trouble calculating total score based on team id. A team can be either home or away and I am looking to calculate a running total of their score.
I have successfully created a running total based on home_id and away_id as well as a running average based on home/away id, but I am struggling to calculate based on both columns
For example if in game 1 home team scores 1 and then in game 2 they are the away team and score 3 I would like to create a column that says they have scored 4 in total up to this point in the dataset
My code so far is:
import pandas as pd

game_data = pd.read_csv('game_data.csv')

game_data['home_avg_home_games'] = game_data.groupby('home_id')['home_score'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(165, min_periods = 0).mean())
game_data['home_avg_against_home_games'] = game_data.groupby('home_id')['away_score'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(165, min_periods = 0).mean())

game_data['away_avg_away_games'] = game_data.groupby('away_id')['away_score'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(165, min_periods = 0).mean())
game_data['away_avg_against_away_games'] = game_data.groupby('away_id')['home_score'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(165, min_periods = 0).mean())

game_data['scored_home_total'] = game_data.groupby('home_id')['home_score'].cumsum()
game_data['scored_away_total'] = game_data.groupby('away_id')['away_score'].cumsum()




game_id
away_id
home_id
away_score
home_score
home_avg_home_games
home_avg_against_home_games
away_avg_away_games
away_avg_against_away_games




446877
138
134
1
4
4
1
1
4


446911
141
139
5
3
3
5
5
3


446873
121
118
3
4
4
3
3
4


446875
137
158
12
3
3
12
12
3


446872
142
110
2
3
3
2
2
3


446876
136
140
2
3
3
2
2
3


446874
143
113
2
6
6
2
2
6


446879
120
144
4
3
3
4
4
3


446871
119
135
15
0
0
15
15
0


446878
141
139
5
3
3
5
5
3


446869
115
109
10
5
5
10
10
5


446889
112
108
9
0
0
9
9
0


446868
145
133
4
3
3
4
4
3


446870
117
147
5
3
3
5
5
3


446867
111
114
6
2
2
6
6
2


446896
121
118
2
0
2
2.5
2.5
2


446910
138
134
5
6
5
3
3
5


446887
141
139
2
3
3
4
4
3


446883
116
146
8
7
7
8
8
7


446886
136
140
10
2
2.5
6
6
2.5


446885
137
158
2
1
2
7
7
2


446882
115
109
6
11
8
8
8
8


446880
112
108
6
1
0.5
7.5
7.5
0.5


446881
145
133
5
4
3.5
4.5
4.5
3.5


446884
119
135
3
0
0
9
9
0


446901
141
139
3
5
3.5
3.75
3.75
3.5


446898
137
158
3
4
2.666666667
5.666666667
5.666666667
2.666666667


446899
136
140
9
5
3.333333333
7
7
3.333333333


446891
115
109
4
3
6.333333333
6.666666667
6.666666667
6.333333333



My desired output is:



game_id
away_id
home_id
away_score
home_score
home_avg_for_home_games
home_avg_against_home_games
away_avg_away_games
away_avg_against_away_games
home_total_score
away_total_score




446877
1
2
1
4
4
1
1
4
4
1


446911
2
3
5
3
3
5
5
3
3
5


446873
1
3
3
4
3.5
4
2
4
7
4




We need to see some code to really be able to help.

Please also can  u give us desired outpuy

This will help you to solve your problem. However it gives warning for avoid warning u need to use include_groups=False however if u that it remove home_id and away_id
game_data = game_data.groupby('home_id',group_keys=False,as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.assign(home_total_score=x['home_score'].cumsum()),include_groups=True)
game_data= game_data.groupby('away_id',group_keys=False,as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.assign(away_total_score=x['away_score'].cumsum()),include_groups=True)

I have solved that issue with like that I created new away_id with using np.where(). So you need to add import numpy as np in your code.
new = game_data.groupby('home_id',group_keys=False,as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.assign(home_total_score=x['home_score'].cumsum()),include_groups=False)
new= game_data.groupby('away_id',group_keys=False,as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.assign(away_total_score=x['away_score'].cumsum()),include_groups=False)

new["away_id"] = np.where(new["game_id"] == game_data["game_id"],game_data["away_id"],None)

For reindex columns add these line codes. Becasue we created new column and it added into last index.
columns = new.columns.tolist()

columns.insert(columns.index('away_score'), columns.pop(columns.index('away_id')))

new = new.reindex(columns=columns)


Thanks Muhammed, I am implementing your solution, but I receive the following error, () got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_groups'

could be a version situation. my pandas is v 2.2.2.  @NateB

can u remove include_groups=False and only use  that part of code
game_data =game_data.groupby('home_id',group_keys=False,as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.assign(home_total_score=x['home_score'].cumsum())) game_data=game_data.groupby('away_id',group_keys=False,as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.assign(away_total_score=x['away_score'].cumsum())) @NateB
